# How can I prevent Race Condition

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I prevent Race Condition in this method:

```
@Lock
 public boolean delete(int id) {
    someEntity byId = someRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException());
    someRepository.delete(byId);
    return true;
}
```

I have done @Lock

```
@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class LockAspect {
    private final ReentrantLock reentrantLock;

public LockAspect() {
    reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();
}

@Around("@annotation(com.example.aspect.Lock)")
public void aroundDelete(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    reentrantLock.lock();
    try {
        proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    } finally {
        reentrantLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

But this lock only blocks the app not really solves the problem the same with

Also I was thing about `@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)` or `@Transactional(isolation= Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)` annotation above the `delete` method  but I'm not sure if that will solve the problem. It is spring app.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of solving this, popular options are:

1. Don't do a separate SELECT, just issue a DELETE. And if you get OptimisticLockException from Hibernate, then you know for sure the record didn't exist. It looks like you're using Spring Data, you can either create a `@Modifying` method for this or just use `repo.getOne()` instead of `repo.findXxx()`.
2. Use Repeatable Read isolation level - the database should return an error if another transaction updated the record concurrently. Eg. here are [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ) (technically in PG this is a Snapshot isolation level though).
3. Use pessimistic locking with `select .. for update`, this will not allow DML operations to proceed with the row until it's unlocked (transaction is finished).

Comment: So I was right with @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ) above the method?

Comment: Yes, that should work. But the 1st option is the simplest. Especially if using a query (which will issue a DELETE right away).